# How to extract all elements in a JSON array using Redshift?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, path, amazon-redshift

I want to extract from a JSON which has more JSONs nested inside, all the elements whose title is 'title2'. I have the code working on MySQL but I can not translate it into Redshift.

JSON structure:
`{"master-title": [{"title": "a", "title2": "b"},{"title": "c", "title2: "d", "title3": "e"}], "master-title2": [{"title": "f", "title2": "g", "title3": "h"},{"title": "i", "title2": "j", "title3": "k"}]}`

MySQL query (works as desired):

```
select id
,json_extract(myJSON, '$**.title2')),0)
from myTable
```

MySQL ouput:
`["b", "d","g","j"]`

My problem is that on Redshift I can only specifically define the path as:
`JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(myJSON, 'master-title2',0,'title')`
So I can only get one element instead of all of them.

Any idea how to evaluate all paths and to get all elements in a JSON array which have the same "title2" using Redshift? (same output as in MySQL)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift has only a very rudimentary set to JSON manipulation functions (basically [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) and [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html)). It's not enough to deal with *schemaless* JSON.

### Python UDF

If Redshift was my only mean of processing data I would give [python UDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html) a try. You can code a function in imperative python. Then, having a column holding your json object and just call that function on all elements to do custom extraction.

### Unnesting JSON arrays

Other options would be to really try to understand the schema and implement it using the two JSON funtions mentioned before ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198745/1680826) SO answer will give you an idea on how to *explode*/*unnest* a JSON array in Redshift). Provided your JSON is not arbitrarily nested, but follows some patterns, this could work.

### Regex (better don't)

Another desperate approach would be to try to extract your data with regex - could work for simple cases, but it's an easy way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.

I finally found a solution using Python. I hope it may help some others.

`count=[x.count("title2") for x in df['myJSON'].tolist()]`