# Redshift get Json Keys

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table field with a value like this:

```
{
    "0fc8a2a1-e334-43b8-9311-ce46da9cd32c": {
        "alert": "345",
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Variant 1"
    },
    "4344d89b-7f0d-4453-b2c5-d0d4a39d7d25": {
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Control Group",
        "type": "control"
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is some way to get the **"0fc8a2a1-e334-43b8-9311-ce46da9cd32c"** and
**"4344d89b-7f0d-4453-b2c5-d0d4a39d7d25"** values.

Comment: Redshift has quite limited JSON support. I suspect that what you ask for for is just not possible.

Comment: What are you looking to be returned?  You have one row's json and you want two answers.  Do you want a comma separated list?  An array? (Redshift doesn't support array type)  What are you doing with this result / is this being passed to another (non-SQL) tool?

Comment: @BillWeiner If I can get them in a comma-separated list that is OK. But by the end, I will need each of them in separated rows

Comment: If the json is this simple then regexp_replace functions that strip the leading / trailing {} and then collapses everything between ': {' and '}' will give you the comma separated string you want.  Then you can use some cross joining to turn this into rows (see "listunagg" thread in stackoverflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redshift is not good with JSON, and especially not good with arbitrary JSON keys (as @GMB mentioned). Also it's not good with nested data structures.

**So actually, you have 2 problems:**

1. **extacting the json keys.** I see 2 options here:

- Use python UDF
- Use regex

2. **unnesting an array of keys into a table**. There's a trick to unnest data into rows (see `CROSS JOIN` with `seq` table in queries belowbelow) - described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195760/return-elements-of-redshift-json-array-on-separate-rows/30198745#30198745).

#### 1. Solution with python UDF

you can implement json parsing in python and register it as a user defined function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

function:

```
create or replace function f_py_json_keys (a varchar(65535))
    returns varchar(65535)
    stable
as $$
    import json
    return ",".join(json.loads(a).keys())
$$ language plpythonu;
```

query:

```
with input(json) as (
    select '{
    "0fc8a2a1-e334-43b8-9311-ce46da9cd32c": {
        "alert": "345",
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Variant 1"
    },
    "4344d89b-7f0d-4453-b2c5-d0d4a39d7d25": {
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Control Group",
        "type": "control"
    }
}'::varchar
), seq(idx) as (
    select 1 UNION ALL
    select 2 UNION ALL
    select 3 UNION ALL
    select 4 UNION ALL
    select 5
), input_with_occurences as (
    select f_py_json_keys(json) as keys,
           regexp_count(keys, ',') + 1 as number_of_occurrences
    from input
)
select
    split_part(keys, ',', idx) as id
from input_with_occurences cross join seq
where idx <= number_of_occurrences
```

#### 2. Solution with REGEX magic

Redshift has some regex functions. That's a working example that would do the job for the payload you specified:

```
with input(json) as (
    select '{
    "0fc8a2a1-e334-43b8-9311-ce46da9cd32c": {
        "alert": "345",
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Variant 1"
    },
    "4344d89b-7f0d-4453-b2c5-d0d4a39d7d25": {
        "channel": "ios_push",
        "name": "Control Group",
        "type": "control"
    }
}'::varchar
), seq(idx) as (
    select 1 UNION ALL
    select 2 UNION ALL
    select 3 UNION ALL
    select 4 UNION ALL
    select 5
), input_with_occurences as (
    select *,
           regexp_count(json,
                        '\\{?\\"([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\\":\\s\\{[\\w\\s\\":,]+\\}') as number_of_occurrences
    from input
)
select
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(json, '\\{?\\"([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\\":\\s\\{[\\w\\s\\":,]+\\}', 1, idx, 'e') as id
       from input_with_occurences cross join seq
        where idx <= number_of_occurrences
```

result looks like:

```
+------------------------------------+
|id                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|0fc8a2a1-e334-43b8-9311-ce46da9cd32c|
|4344d89b-7f0d-4453-b2c5-d0d4a39d7d25|
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Running the "REGEX" version as you coded works Perfectly. But it doesn't work when using my real database... I have made a few tests and it looks like it is not working because, in my data, the JSON field isn't ""prettified", its just a single row. And I guess this Rexex expects a real JSON format... Any workaround? PS: Thanks in advance, your answer is amazing

Comment: Ended up, after a few tries, I could make it works using this simplified regex: '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}'

Answer (score 7):

Although a year have past since this question was opened, but I found how to use it using Redshift native capabilities.

Redshift has a SUPER column type that stores native JSONs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html

And can be queried using PartiQL:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

https://partiql.org/tutorial.html

Assuming a table called `MyTable` with a column named `data` of type SUPER that can store JSON, I have created the following query:

```
SELECT
  key
FROM
  MyTable AS t,
  UNPIVOT t.data AS value AT key;
```

- In case of JSON arrays, the syntax `x AS y AT z` means `"foreach Y in X"` where `z` is the index of object `y` inside an array `x`
- In case of unpivoting JSON objects, the syntax means the same for `x` and `y`, but `z` is the key, instead of the index (When you think about it, also array can be represented in an Object manner, where the index is the key: `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', ... }

The query results are:

```
create temp table if not exists MyTable(
  data SUPER
);
insert into MyTable VALUES (json_parse('{"a": 1, "b":2}'));

select key from MyTable as t, unpivot t.data as value at key;
```

[image]