# Unnest an array in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, unnest

I have a table with column with lists like this:

```
id
[1,2,3,10]
[1]
[2,3,4,9]
```

The result I would like to have is a table with unlisted values like this:

```
id2
1
2
3
10
1
2
3
4
9
```

I have tried different solutions that I found on the web, [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data-sqlextensions.html), [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195760/return-elements-of-redshift-json-array-on-separate-rows), [blog post](http://torsten.io/stdout/expanding-json-arrays-to-rows/), but without any luck because I have a list in column and not a json object.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the dataatype of that column?

Comment: @GMB How to see that in redshift?

Comment: Have you tried something with unnest(ARRAY[...])?

Comment: @ecp Yup, for example just to see if it works, I tried `SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2])`, and it throws an error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "unnest" Position: 78`

Comment: @Makaroni . . . Redshift does not support arrays.  Hence, the question doesn't really make sense and you need to explain what the column type is.

Comment: Lets just assume the column type is VARCHAR and move on with a solution. OP already said not working with JSON.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update (2022): Redshift now supports arrays and allows to "unnest" them easily.

The syntax is simply to have a `FROM the_table AS the_table_alias, the_table_alias.the_array AS the_element_alias`

Here's an example with the data mentioned in the question:

```
WITH
  -- some table with test data
  input_data as (
    SELECT array(1,2,3,10)  as  id
    union all
    SELECT  array(1)  as id
    union all
    SELECT  array(2,3,4,9)  as id
  ) 


SELECT 
  id2 
FROM 
  input_data AS ids, 
  ids.id AS id2
```

Yields the expected:

```
id2
---
1
2
3
4
9
1
2
3
10
```

See here for more details and examples with deeper nesting levels: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

Answer (score 2):

What is the dataatype of that column?

Redshift does not support arrays, so let me assume this is a JSON string.

Redshift does not provide JSON set-returning functions: we need to unnest manually. Here is one way to do it, if you have a table with a sufficient numbers of rows (at least as many rows as there are elements in the array) - say  `sometable`:

```
select json_extract_array_element_text(t.id, n.rn) as new_id
from mytable t
inner join (select row_number() over() - 1 as rn from sometable) n
    on n.rn < json_array_length(t.id)
```

Comment: Can a similar thing be constructed assuming the column type is not json but VARCHAR?  `'[1,2,3...]'` delimited by commas?  Maybe we can use `split_part` instead of json_extract_array_element_text. `split_part(t.id, ',', n.rn)` and also change json_array_length to get number of elements in varchar column.

Answer (score 1):

I played around to get the same result on array column using recursive CTE, here's something what I come up. I'm sure there is a better way but here it is anyway..

```
WITH recursive unnested(id, elem, idx) AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        arr_column [0] AS elem,
        0 AS idx
    FROM
        nest_column_table
    WHERE
        id = 1
    UNION
    ALL
    SELECT
        (
            CASE
                WHEN umi.idx + 2 >= get_array_length(ci.arr_column) THEN umi.id + 1
                ELSE umi.id
            END
        ) AS id,
        arr_column [umi.idx + 1] AS elem,
        (
            CASE
                WHEN umi.idx + 2 >= get_array_length(ci.arr_column) THEN -1
                ELSE umi.idx + 1
            END
        ) AS idx
    FROM
        nest_column_table ci
        INNER JOIN unnested umi ON umi.id = ci.id
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    unnested;
```