# Regex in Amazon Redshift using SQL

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm using sql in amazon redshift. I have a column called attributes which looks like this:

```
[{"name": "Size", "value": "Small"},{"name": "Color", "value": "Blue"},{"name": "Material", "value": "Cotton"}]
```

or

```
[{"name": "Material", "value": "silk"},{"name": "Color", "value": "Pink"}]
```

In order to extract the material value, I'm trying to use regex. I have the initial code such:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(attributes,'Material.*') as string_value
```

**Result**:

```
Material", "value": "Cotton"}]
```

and

```
Material", "value": "silk"},{"name": "Color", "value": "Pink"}]
```

How can I take this a step further and get just the value of material, **so output should look like**:

```
Cotton

silk
```

I'm new to sql and new to regex so would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and capture groups:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(attributes, '"Material", "value": "([^"]*)"') as string_value
```

Comment: I modified your suggestion to this: 

select REGEXP_SUBSTR(attributes, '"Material", "value": "([^"]*)"') as string_value
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_value, ':.*') as material_value.

Example result is 
: "Cotton" 

How could I remove the : and the two " to get just Cotton? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably *not* be resorting to using regex to parse JSON content, especially given that your JSON content is nested inside an array.  I am admittedly not an expert in the Redshift JSON API, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195760/return-elements-of-redshift-json-array-on-separate-rows/30198745#30198745) was very helpful.  Consider the following approach:

```sql
CREATE VIEW seq_0_to_3 AS
    SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL                                      
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2          
);

WITH exploded_array AS (                                                                          
    SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(json_col, seq.i) AS json
    FROM yourTable, seq_0_to_3 AS seq
    WHERE seq.i < JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(json_col)
)

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json, 'value') AS Material
FROM exploded_array
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json, 'name') = 'Material';
```

This answer assumes that your JSON arrays would always have 3 elements for the size, color, and material.  If the count would differ from 3, then update the view `seq_0_to_3` above with the correct number of elements.