# Convert SUPER field array of json objects into rows for single field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Assume I have a Redshift table `my_schema.my_table` that contains a record as such:

```
id   col1   my_list
-------------------
1    true   [{"id": "A", "name": "foo"}, {"id": "B", "name": "bar"}]
```

The column `my_list` is a `SUPER` field. My understanding is that I would need to somehow iterate over the array, using `get_array_length(my_list)` and I recognize I can extract elements as such:

```
select
  my_list[0]."id",
  my_list[0]."name"
from my_schema.my_table
```

Is there a simple Redshift method for doing this and ultimately achieving a table that looks as such:

```
id   name
---------
A    foo
B    bar
```

Important to note, that this should happen dynamically. I will not know the size of the array. But the same key value pairs will always exist, i.e. `id` and `name`.

---

EDIT: Here is my best guess.

```
SELECT
  my_list[idx]."id",
  my_list[idx]."name"
FROM my_schema.my_table
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT generate_series(0, GET_ARRAY_LENGTH(my_list) - 1) AS idx
  FROM my_schema.my_table
) AS idx_table
```

but I am getting the error:

`[0A000] ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return elements of Redshift JSON array on separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195760/return-elements-of-redshift-json-array-on-separate-rows)

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: why not, you have a json and need to unest it, as you can read readsiht has not that much json support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible within Redshift. You would first need to iterate over `my_list` and create a single row per list item. Once you do that, you are able to parse out whatever fields you need from each individual array.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT item
    FROM my_schema.table t, t.my_list AS item AT index
)
select item.{whatever-key} from cte
```